# move files with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, filepath

I am trying to move a file with AppleScript. This Is the code I use:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in these_items
        set this_item to item i of these_items
        set the item_info to info for this_item
        set the item_path to the quoted form of the POSIX path of this_item

...
...   //irrelevant code here
...


       tell application "Finder"
         move POSIX file item_path to POSIX file "/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Books"
       end tell

    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

If I replace `item_path` with a regular path such as `/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Test/test.png` than it works great. What could be the reason for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`these_items` is an array of `alias` specifiers, any further coercion is not needed

```
tell application "Finder"
     move this_item to folder "Books" of desktop
end tell
```

the property `desktop` points always to the desktop of the current user.

By the way: The Finder doesn't accept POSIX paths (slash separated), only the native HFS paths (colon separated).

PS: The reason why `item_path` does not work is the quotation.
It's only needed in `do shell script`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    tell application "Finder" to move these_items to folder "Books" of desktop
end adding folder items to
```

The `after receiving` parameter is a list of AppleScript alias values, which is something Finder's `move` command already understands and knows how to work with. While it's unusual for application commands like `move` to accept values that aren't references to application objects, it's not completely unknown; particularly with pre-OS X apps like Finder whose scripting support was completely hand-written, allowing developers to make it work in ways that would be helpful to users and not just in ways dictated by dumb, standardized frameworks like OS X's Cocoa Scripting.